# d3.js how to merge with transition + add mouse event?

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js, tooltip

I am trying to create a bar chart like in the following example https://d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/barplot_button_data_hard.html with tooltips on mouseover.

It does not work because there is a transition before calling the mouse event (reason see answer [D3: When I add a transition, my mouseover stops working... why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645162/d3-when-i-add-a-transition-my-mouseover-stops-working-why) )

However, even if I split the calls, it still does not work or I break the merge transition. Does anybody have an idea how to fix this? This is my current code:

```
let u = this.svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data);

    u.enter()
        .append("rect") // Add a new rect for each new elements
        .merge(u)
        .transition() // and apply changes to all of them
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("x", (d: any) => { return this.x(d.date); })
        .attr("y", (d: any) => { return this.y(d.value); })
        .attr("width", this.x.bandwidth())
        .attr("height", (d: any) => { return this.height - this.y(d.value); })
        u.on('mouseover', (event: any, d: any) => {
            d3.select('#tooltip').transition().duration(200).style('opacity', 1);
            d3.select('#tooltip').html(`Dividend: <span>${d.value}</span>`)
                .style('left', `${event.x}px`)
                .style('opacity', `1`)
                .style('top', `${(event.y - 28)}px`);
          }).on('mousemove', (event: any, d: any) =>
            d3.select('#tooltip')
            .style('left', `${event.x}px`)
            .style('top', `${(event.y - 28)}px`
          )).on('mouseout', () => d3.select('#tooltip').transition().duration(200).style('opacity', 0));
```

Comment: it does work without .transition().duration(1000). This way I can simply add .on('mouseover') after the last .attr() without having to call it on "u" again.

Comment: .transition returns the transition, not the selection, so you could do your mouseover lines after .merge and before .transition if you want it to be in one chain (this is also why removing .transition().duration() works as you note your comment). You can also use transition.selection() to return the selection being transitioned.